# Git GUI + GitHub, amend last commit is problematic, how to quickly overcome it?

Tags: git, github, commit

The problem is on `git gui` VERSUS github (when I try to push an ammended commit created with `git gui`).

Many times, instead of promptly pushing, I just code more.
When I go to commit and push using `git gui`, some times I select "amend last commit" just to reuse the commit message at `git gui`.

When I remember that this interaction (`git gui` vs GitHub) will mess things up, I copy the comment at "ammend last commit" option, and select "new commit" back again, and paste the comment on it.
But right now I forgot and I am on such mess again... GitHub will not allow me to push the ammended commit, it wants me to merge things unnecessarily (because the ammend commit should work, and simply does not).
So now, my source files are messed (requiring merge, with that merge tags all over preventing compilation), and there are like 20 files messed...

I have not a previous backup.
So I could painfully get my previous commit in some way (using some git command line)... but I guess there is some straight forward way to overwrite the files modified to allow manual merging with my latest proper changes.

I am the only one committing files, so this is a `git gui` versus GitHub bug or limitation for sure.

Summary:
1) do commit, commit, commit...
2) do ammend last commit (it may or not cause problem)
3) do `git pull` (it may create merge tags messing the files, uncompilable, requiring needles conflict resolve)

From @VonC answer `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all`, the fork seems very clear:

```
* d8f3505 (HEAD, master) improving savable helper
| * 772a6c0 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) improving savable helper
|/  
* 15630f3 improving savable helper
```

or

```
* fdc9ae1 (HEAD, master) improving savable helper
| * 772a6c0 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) improving savable helper
|/  
* 15630f3 improving savable helper
```

so, my latest changes are at d8f3505 or fdc9ae1 (I recovered backups to retry, thats why such number changed).

this command keeps the merge tags, therefore uncompilable: `git reset origin/master`

this command `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` restores the changes at 772a6c0, therefore I lose the latest ones (I still have the backup).

So, how to make the latest (d8f3505 or fdc9ae1 or another new one as soon I recover the backup again), be the one that will win/overwrite the HEAD?

EDIT:
using `git reset --hard 12eb50c` (the new id) let me recover the latest changes without merge tags, great!

but now, after `git rebase origin/master` (that messes the files again, but now I had time to backup the files, in a non test case situation...), I get this message from `git gui`:
[image]
after I accept it, the push from within `git gui` stopped working, but command line `git push` gives me this message:

```
To https://USER@github.com/USER/PROJECT.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://USER@github.com/USER/PROJECT.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. If you did not intend to push that branch, you may want to
hint: specify branches to push or set the 'push.default' configuration variable
hint: to 'simple', 'current' or 'upstream' to push only the current branch.
```

unable to push even after `git reset --hard 15630f3`... if I could prune whatever is after it and just overwrite with my backuped sources...

Comment: It's not clear from your question what problem you're seeing on GitHub. Without knowing the problem it's difficult to suggest a solution.

Comment: please make question clearer

Comment: @JanKrüger I re-read it and is was confusing indeed, I was in a hurry.

Comment: @SKandeel is it clear now? or there is something else still obscure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By selecting amend the last commit, you have actually rewritten your HEAD instead of creating a new commit (which would have been pushed to GitHub without issue)

```
 --o--o (origin/master)
    \
     -O (HEAD: your amended commit)
```

Since the history is now different, GitHub (or any remote Git repo) wants you to pull and merge first, then push.

In order to fix this, since the content in O is good for you, but the commit itself is not, you can:

- reset HEAD to `origin/master`, but keeping your current working tree

  ```
  git reset origin/master
  ```
- add and commit from there: this should add your work as a new commit.

From there, you can push your new commit without any issue (fast-forward)

**Alternatively:**

Find out what is your last changes with:
`git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` (it will be the top one, not the forked one)

Then do this ex.: `reset --hard fdc9ae1` and backup your restored last sources changes.

Then `git checkout master` and `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`

It will require `git pull` before `git push`, do it, the merge tags will appear again...

Replace with your backup, and now you can push properly again.

---

Note: to quickly "Amend the last commit" with git gui (Git 2.24, Q4 2019):
Toggle amend on and off with the keyboard shortcut "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>".

See [commit ec7424e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec7424e1a634ba4a509227f003bd9cf31f12b4c2) (14 Sep 2019) by [Birger Skogeng Pedersen (``)](https://github.com/).
See [commit ba41b5b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ba41b5b335b00ac1cb277c83b87ebf3c26b670c0) (13 Sep 2019) by [Bert Wesarg (`bertwesarg`)](https://github.com/bertwesarg).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7e1976e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e1976e2100da661e858e3aa12ae2c8d152431c2), 18 Sep 2019)</sup>

Comment: it looks like we create a kind of fork or branch when we do the "ammend last commit", I wonder if it wouldnt be cleaner to `git gui` to create some kind of diff and then provide us with a normal new commit, because that merge we are required to do still looks pointless right? at least let us disable that tempting ammend checkbox... Btw, it seems kind dificult to recreate the problem, I am still trying to make it happen again, I will try some commits with some ammends and push to see if it happens again, it feels like it is waiting the worst time to happen hehe..

Comment: @AquariusPower you can see the fork after an amend with a `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all`

Comment: so, I managed to make the problem happen (still dont understand how, the ammend worked many times, and suddenly required merge). Then I did `git pull` that messed my files with merge tags. Then I tried `git reset origin/master`, but the files still contain the merge tags and are still messed. Should I have tried the reset before `git pull`?

Comment: @AquariusPower another approach is to reset everything: git reset --hard HEAD@{1} (to get back to O), and then: git rebase origin/master: to replay O on top of origin/master. After that (which might involve conflict resolution), a simple git push will be enough.

Comment: I updated the question with the new tests, there is easier to format the text. I am still losing the latest changes. Seems quite complicated this one :)

Comment: @AquariusPower if you know the right commit, simply: `git reset --hard <the_right_SHA1>`, and then, as before, `git rebase origin/master`

Comment: great! that lets me recover my latest changes! so I have time enough to backup them! but I got a message just before the commit, I put the image on the question OP too.

Comment: @AquariusPower once your commit is done, reset the master branch to your new HEAD: `git branch -M master`: then `git checkout master`, and then `git push`.

Comment: `git branch -M master` gives this: "error: refname refs/heads/HEAD not found" "fatal: Branch rename failed"

Comment: @AquariusPower OK: what about: `git checkout master`, followed by `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`?

Comment: `git checkout master` asks me to `git pull`, with this message: "Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)"  I will do it and I guess I will have the merge tags again, but may be I can push again?

Comment: I did `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` still no git pull

Comment: @AquariusPower the idea is to make sure `master` reference the right commit. Ignore any "`git pull`" message. Just replace the second `git reset --hard` with the right commit if `HEAD@{1}`. Then do a `git status` and a `git log` to be sure you are on the right commit *and* the right branch (`master`). And then rebase it on top of origin/master with `git rebase origin/master`. Finally push (no pull required then).

Comment: so, after `git checkout master` and `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`, if I tried to push it would reject. It required yet a `git pull`, that messed the files, so I just restored the backup over it, and `git gui` allowed me to push again and it succeeded !

Comment: mind I update your answer with these steps or you think there is a better way?